# ImportError when running Kivy application on Android

Tags: android, kivy, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a Kivy application on Android, but I am encountering an ImportError. I am using Kivy version 2.2.0 and Python 3.10.10. Here is the relevant snippet from the log:

`ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_PyGen_Send" referenced by "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/_event.so"...`

The error seems to indicate that it cannot locate the symbol "_PyGen_Send" when trying to load the "_event.so" file from Kivy. I have checked the library configurations and search paths, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

I have followed the Python for Android initialization steps as mentioned in the Kivy documentation. Additionally, I have verified that the required libraries are present in the correct path. However, the error persists.